# Eclipse spell checker - How do I remove a word I added?

Tags: java, eclipse, spell-checking

I accidentally added a word I'm forever mis-spelling into Eclipse's spell-checker dictionary. How do I get it back out again?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eclipse puts the words you add into a text file, AKA the *User defined dictionary*.

You can find the location of this file at *Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Spelling -> User defined dictionary*.

I believe that it's not set up by default - the first time you use the *Add to dictionary* feature it asks for the user dictionary location.

Open up the file in a text editor and remove the word you don't want.  You'll probably need to restart Eclipse before it recognises the word as misspelled again (i.e. before it will re-read the user dictionary file).

Comment: You did post a comprehensive answer before mine. +1

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [bug 51445](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=51445), the user defined dictionary is any text file, by default with a '.dic'  extension (but you can use any or no extension if you like).

The [help page](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-36.htm) help you to locate that file.

[alt text http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/ref-spellingpref.png](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/ref-spellingpref.png)

As mentioned in [bug 111265](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=111265) (comment 2), you need to relaunch eclipse...