# Eclipse spell checker - How do I remove a word I didn't add?

Tags: eclipse, spell-checking

I noticed when I type a word it is NOT flagged as misspelled by the Eclipse spell checker, but I'd like it to be.  The word is not in my user dictionary.  How can I tell Eclipse that I'd like that word to be flagged as misspelled?  Is this possible?

I came across this similar question, but it only describes how to remove a word that I myself accidentally added...  [Eclipse spell checker - How do I remove a word I added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362400/eclipse-spell-checker-how-do-i-remove-a-word-i-added)

I suppose, more specifically, what I want to do is make updates to my copy of a Platform dictionary.

Comment: I think I may have found an answer to my own question.  I discovered this link http://www.norio.be/blog/2008/11/using-aspell-dictionary-eclipse where it describes how an aspell dictionary can be converted to a user dictionary which effectively can replace a platform dictionary altogether.  Then the platform dictionary can be set to none.

However, as for how to edit an existing platform dictionary or create my own custom platform dictionary I have not really found out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The platform dicts are located in `%eclipse%/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/70/1/.cp/dictionaries` in my case.
If the numbers are different for you, just search for 'dict', and there'll be only one result. The files are plain-text just like your user dictionary.

Btw, just wondering which word it is that's incorrectly flagged as correct by the platform dict.